# CRTP and overload return type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, decltype

Consider the following code :

```
template <class Crtp>
struct Base
{
    const float& get(const short int i) const {return std::get<0>(tuple);}
    const double& get(const int i) const {return std::get<1>(tuple);}
    const long double& get(const unsigned long long int i) const {return std::get<2>(tuple);}
    std::tuple<float, double, long double> tuple;
};

struct Derived
: public Base<Derived>
{
    template <class... Misc, class Return = /*SOMETHING*/>
    const Return& test(Misc&&... misc) const
    {return this->get(std::forward<Misc>(misc)...);} 
};
```

This is an EXAMPLE code: it does not illustrate something useful, and the problem could be solved using an auto function declaration for instance. I know that and I do not search a workaround concerning this particular example.

My question is : what would be `/*SOMETHING*/` in order to get the return type of the correct overload of `get` depending of the passed `Misc` types ?

Comment: The same you'd do with a deduced return? This should work just fine: `class Return = decltype(this->get(std::declval<Misc>()...))`.

Comment: @Xeo: If I say that, can I replace the `const Return&` by `Return`?

Comment: If you want to "perfect-return", i.e. return exactly what the base function gives you, then yes.

Comment: @Xeo: `invalid use of ‘this’ at top level`, but I think that a `declval` of `Derived` should be ok.

Comment: @Xeo Probably `std::declval<const Derived>().get(...)` works.

Comment: @KennyTM Why `const Derived` and not simply `Derived` ?

Comment: @Vincent: Since `test` is `const`, the call in the body will also have a `const Derived` and it should match up.

Comment: Nice Xeo! Ok, thanks, problem solved!
@Xeo : you can just copy past `class Return = decltype(std::declval<const Derived>().get(std::declval<Misc>()...))` and I will validate your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using `decltype` with `std::declval` (from `<type_traits>`) should be fine:

```
class Return = decltype(std::declval<Derived const>().get(std::declval<Misc>()...))
```